# Modern Experience Upload-Metadata Problem

Tags: metadata, modern-experience, modern-document-library

In the classic experience when the user uses the upload button the user gets asked to enter the Metedata.
In the modern experience, when I use the upload button no pop up window open up to ask me about filling the necessary metadata.
I know users can, go and check files that need attention and then file in the metadata.
Is there any other solution to this ? 
The continuity is the old experience was good, click upload file, window opens up, asks you to add metadata and then done .

How do you guys deal with this if you are using the new experience

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOTB way to deal with it. Required columns are completely ignored in the modern SharePoint UI. All we get is the visual indicators in the list View or a list item form.

The only potential solution would to be change the settings for that particular document library to use the classic view.

Answer (score 0):

So far we have had to revert to classic if updated metadata is a must, otherwise loads of training AND appointed data owners that has to remind the users if they have forgotten the mandatory fields. In some cases we have a workflow that sends an automatic reminder